# JS - Drag and Drop assistance

Tags: javascript, html

I have a current working html/js code that allows me to move 4 objects into their respective DIV attributes, however, I'm completely confused on how to go about getting an alert to pop up once the user has ALL the images in their respective place. If anyone has a better way or can point me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it. Here's my jsfiddle link below:

https://jsfiddle.net/crizil/z2zd6bfk/1/

```
<body>
  <img id="puzzle1" src="images/puzzle1.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragEvent(event)" 
width="500" height="100">
  <img id="puzzle2" src="images/puzzle2.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragEvent(event)" 
width="500" height="100">
  <img id="puzzle3" src="images/puzzle3.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragEvent(event)" 
width="500" height="100">
  <img id="puzzle4" src="images/puzzle4.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragEvent(event)" 
width="500" height="100">

  <div id="div1" ondrop="dropPic(event)" ondragover="dropEvent(event)" data-    drop="puzzle1">
  </div>  
  <div id="div2" ondrop="dropPic(event)" ondragover="dropEvent(event)" data-    drop="puzzle2">
  </div> 
  <div id="div3" ondrop="dropPic(event)" ondragover="dropEvent(event)" data-    drop="puzzle3">
  </div>   
  <div id="div4" ondrop="dropPic(event)" ondragover="dropEvent(event)" data-    drop="puzzle4">
  </div>
 </body>

    //allow ability to drop objects
    function dropEvent(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
     }

    //allow image dragging
    function dragEvent(ev) {
      ev.dataTransfer.setData('text', ev.target.id);
    }

    //drop image event
    function dropPic(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData('text');
    //make it to only drop in certain DIV attribute
       if (ev.target.getAttribute('data-drop') == data)
           ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
     }
```

If I need to further clarify what I'm trying to do, let me know and I'll hopefully have a better way to communicate what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a counter and check if it's equal to `document.querySelectorAll('[data-drop]').length`:

```
var counter = 0;
function dropPic(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData('text');
      //make it to only drop in certain DIV attribute
      if (ev.target.getAttribute('data-drop') == data) {
           ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
           if (++counter == document.querySelectorAll('[data-drop]').length) {
              alert('all done');
           }
      }
}
```